# Spark Structured Streaming - compare two streams

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using Kafka and Spark 2.1 Structured Streaming. I have two topics with data in json format eg:

```
topic 1:

{"id":"1","name":"tom"}
{"id":"2","name":"mark"}

topic 2:

{"name":"tom","age":"25"}
{"name":"mark","age:"35"}
```

I need to compare those two streams in Spark base on tag:name and when value is equal execute some additional definition/function.

How to use Spark Structured Streaming to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: How long do you want to keep the state between loading the data from topics? The records may be produced at different times.

Comment: The gap between related events in topics should be max 15 minutes,

Comment: for spark 2.3: https://databricks.com/blog/2018/03/13/introducing-stream-stream-joins-in-apache-spark-2-3.html

Answer (score 0):

Following the current documentation (Spark 2.1.1)

> Any kind of joins between two streaming Datasets are not yet
>   supported.

ref: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#unsupported-operations

At this moment, I think you need to rely on Spark Streaming as proposed by @igodfried's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you got your solution. In case not, then you can try creating two KStreams from two topics and then join those KStreams and put joined data back to one topic. Now you can read the joined data as one DataFrame using Spark Structured Streaming. Now you'll be able to apply any transformations you want on the joined data. Since Structured streaming doesn't support join of two streaming DataFrames you can follow this approach to get the task done.

Comment: yes I know. This was asked a year back. When it was not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar requirement some time ago: I had 2 streams which had to be "joined" together based on some criteria. What I used was a function called **mapGroupsWithState**.

What this functions does (in few words, more details on the reference below) is to take stream in the form of (K,V) and accumulate together its elements on a common state, based on the key of each pair. Then you have ways to tell Spark when the state is *complete* (according to your application), or even have a timeout for incomplete states.

Example based on your question:

1. Read Kafka topics into a Spark Stream:

   ```
   val rawDataStream: DataFrame = spark.readStream
   .format("kafka")
   .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers)
   .option("subscribe", "topic1,topic2") // Both topics on same stream!
   .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
   .option("failOnDataLoss", "true")
   .load()
   .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as jsonData") // Kafka sends bytes
   ```
2. Do some operations on your data (I prefer SQL, but you can use the DataFrame API) to transform each element into a key-value pair:

   ```
   spark.sqlContext.udf.register("getKey", getKey) // You define this function; I'm assuming you will be using the name as key in your example.

   val keyPairsStream = rawDataStream
   .sql("getKey(jsonData) as ID, jsonData from rawData")
   .groupBy($"ID")
   ```
3. Use the **mapGroupsWithState** function (I will show you the basic idea; you will have to define the *myGrpFunct* according to your needs):

   ```
   keyPairsStream
   .mapGroupsWithState(GroupStateTimeout.ProcessingTimeTimeout())(myGrpFunct)
   ```
4. Thats it! If you implement *myGrpFunct* correctly, you will have one stream of merged data, which you can further transform, like the following:

["tom",{"id":"1","name":"tom"},{"name":"tom","age":"25"}]

["mark",{"id":"2","name":"mark"},{"name":"mark","age:"35"}]

Hope this helps!

An **excellent explanation** with some code snippets: http://asyncified.io/2017/07/30/exploring-stateful-streaming-with-spark-structured-streaming/

Answer (score -1):

One method would be to transform both streams into (K,V) format. In your case this would probably take the form of (name, otherJSONData)  See the [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#) for more information on joining streams and an example located [here](https://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/latest/databricks_guide/07%20Spark%20Streaming/13%20Joining%20DStreams.html). Then do a join on both streams and then perform whatever function on the newly joined stream. If needed you can use map to return (K,(W,V)) to (K,V).

Comment: The OP's asking about **Structured Streaming** (not Spark Streaming!)